# xsl for-each to create an iterable node list

Tags: xslt

I need to iterate over the elements of an XML file in sorted order of their language field many times. What I try is to get an iterable list of the languages as follows:

```
<xsl:variable name="languages">
  <xsl:for-each select="elem/FIELD[@NAME='language']">
    <xsl:sort select="."/>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

While I can verify with a

```
<xsl:value-of select="$languages"/>
```

that the sorting works, I cannot iterate like

```
<xsl:for-each select="$langauges">...</xsl:for-each>
```

because the XSL processor complains that select expression does not evaluate to a node set.

**Edit:** Not sure whether this is important, but I have

```
<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" 
          method="xml" 
          media-type="text/xml" 
          indent="yes" />
```

What do I have to insert in the loop to make the result into a node set? Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you say that

> XSL processor complains that select expression does not evaluate to a node set.

I assume you're using XSLT 1.0 rather than 2.0.  In XSLT 1.0 when you declare a variable with content rather than a `select` attribute, the resulting variable contains something called a "result tree fragment" rather than a node set.  You can apply `value-of` and `copy-of` to a RTF to send it to the output but you can't navigate into it using XPath expressions.

Most XSLT processors provide some sort of extension function to convert a RTF into a real node set - [msxsl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hz88kef0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the Microsoft processor or [exslt](http://www.exslt.org/exsl/index.html) for most others.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
                exclude-result-prefixes="exsl">

  <!-- .... -->

  <xsl:variable name="languagesRTF">
    <xsl:for-each select="elem/FIELD[@NAME='language']">
      <xsl:sort select="."/>
      <lang><xsl:value-of select="."/></lang>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:variable name="languages" select="exsl:node-set($languagesRTF)/lang" />
```

In XSLT 2.0 there is no distinction between result tree fragments and node sets - they're both treated as sequences - so you don't need the extension function in that version.

Answer (score 1):

XSLT 1.0 allows you to process a node-set in sorted order, but it doesn't allow you to save a sorted sequence in a variable (the data model only has sets, not sequences). The only way you can save sorted data in 1.0 is to construct a new tree containing copies of the original elements in a different order, and then use the node-set() extension to make this tree processable.

This changes in XSLT 2.0, which has a data model based on sequences. In 2.0 you can save a sorted sequence of nodes in a variable without copying the nodes into a new tree.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

To declare variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="languages">
 <xsl:for-each select="elem/FIELD[@NAME='language']">
  <xsl:sort select="."/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

And to loop:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$languages/*">
```

Comment: No luck, neither with xsltproc nor with xalan. Still "does not evaluate to a node-set".

Comment: Can you post your whole XSLT, and input XML. Might help in debugging

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but I can't its proprietary information from a customer's database. I'll see if I can simulate the problem with a minimal example, but this may take some time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the result tree fragment in your variable into a node-set, using the [EXSLT node-set() function](http://www.exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/index.html).