# xslt-1.0 iterate over fixed list of values

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to generate an XML structure for a fixed number of languages from an input that may or may not contain information for each language. If the information is missing, I need to generate empty elements. The problem is, that I need to iterate over the languages at many places in the output structure.

The easiest way would be to use something resembling

```
<xsl:variable name="languages" select="en,de,fr">
<xsl:for-each select="$languages">
...
</xsl:for-each>
```

with the loop appearing wherever I need the language list.

Of course this does not work, because `select="en,de,fr"` does not define a node-list. With an extension I could use the `node-set` function, but I am stuck with XSLT-1.0.

Is there any way to define a constant node-set to iterate over?

(This is somehow related to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22835313/xsl-for-each-to-create-an-iterable-node-list) where the accepted answer kills many ideas of creating a constant node set, in particular everything that needs sub-element of `<xsl:variable/>`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a *constant* node set rather than one whose contents are calculated by `xsl:` instructions, then you can do a trick with `document('')` which gives you access to the XML tree of the stylesheet itself:

```
<xsl:variable name="languagesLiteral">
  <lang>en</lang>
  <lang>de</lang>
  <lang>fr</lang>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="languages"
     select="document('')//xsl:variable[@name='languagesLiteral']/*" />
```

This only works for static values, if you had for example `<xsl:variable name="foo"><xsl:for-each ...>` then the node set you get from the `document('')` trick would be the `xsl:for-each` element, not the result of evaluating it.

Comment: Luckily in my use-case only static values are needed.

Comment: Well, in the meantime I learned about an ugly side effect: When I loop over $languages, inside the loop I don't seem to be able anymore to access the original document. A `<xsl:value-of select="/"/>` returns nothing :-( Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @Harald you have to store it away in a variable `<xsl:variable name="root" select="/" />` before you enter the for-each (it could be a global variable at the top level of the stylesheet) and use `$root/whatever`. As you've discovered, `/` on its own means the root of the current document, and inside a for-each over `$languages` that means the stylesheet (`document('')`).

Comment: @Harald note you'd have exactly the same problem with the `exslt:node-set()` approach - `/` would be the root of the document fragment that was converted to a node set, not the original root of the input.

Comment: Thanks a lot. After seeing the `$root` solution, at least this one is obvious, but I was in the completely-puzzled-mode. XSL keeps being a serious time-sink:-(

Comment: @Harald there will come a moment when it suddenly starts to make sense :-) XSLT requires quite a different way of thinking about your problems if you're used to procedural/OO languages rather than functional ones.